# Amazon OpsWorks custom cookbook RVM

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, rvm, chef-infra

I'm trying to install RVM with Amazon OpsWorks using the following cookbook https://github.com/fnichol/chef-rvm. I want rvm to run under the user tomcat6, so I included the recipe rvm::user with the correct attributes.

The error I'm getting is:

> Wed, 06 Mar 2013 20:05:05 +0000 ERROR: Running exception handlers
>   Wed, 06 Mar 2013 20:05:05 +0000 ERROR: Exception handlers complete
>   Wed, 06 Mar 2013 20:05:05 +0000 DEBUG: Re-raising exception: LoadError - no such file to load -- rvm
>   /opt/aws/opsworks/current/site-cookbooks/rvm/recipes/default.rb:29:in `require'
>   /opt/aws/opsworks/current/site-cookbooks/rvm/recipes/default.rb:29:in`from_file'

And the piece of code raising the exception is:

```
chef_gem 'rvm' do
action :install
version '>= 1.11.3.6'
end

ruby_block "require rvm" do
    block do
        require 'rvm'
        create_rvm_shell_chef_wrapper
        create_rvm_chef_user_environment
     end
     action :create
end
```

After getting the error I logged in the instance with ssh and checked whether or not the rvm gem was installed. I could not see rvm listed under *** LOCAL GEMS ***.

Then I replaced the method chef_gem with gem_package and still got the same error. But this time when I checked gem list rvm was listed.

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: hopefully this will help when implemented => http://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-4008

Answer (score 4):

The problem is highlighted here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=118646

OpsWorks' chef implementation is pretty restricted by Amazon. When chef is run on the node, it is actually run via a bundle. Since the rvm cookbook is installing a new gem (rvm) into the system and is attempting to make use of it, it fails since the rvm gem is not *already* part of the bundle (listed in the Gemfile).

The current workaround as of this writing is that opsworks has implemented a method to support the usage of custom gems.

I've been able to update the lines you mentioned with:

```
if defined?(OpsWorks) && defined?(OpsWorks::InternalGems)
  OpsWorks::InternalGems.internal_gem_package('rvm', :version => node['rvm']['chef_internal_rvm_gem_version'])
else
  chef_gem 'rvm' do
    action :install
    version '>= 1.11.3.6'
  end
end
```

Let me know if this works for you!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you used the most recent rvm cookbook? Look at [recipes/default.rb](https://github.com/fnichol/chef-rvm/blob/master/recipes/default.rb) that gave you an error - contents of this file is different from what you posted in your description.